# How to read the Firebase serviceAccountCredentials.json with appengine servlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, firebase

I'm trying to write to the Firebase database following [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start) instructions. I'm using a servlet running in Appengine and the error happens when trying to read the serviceAccountCredentials.json file.

Here is part of the code where the problem happens:

```
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://my-database.firebaseio.com/")
            .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/My File-89b47a8357ff.json"))
            .build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

And here is the logcat output:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\My File-89b47a8357ff.json" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:429)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:135)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
at com.example.myexample.myapplication.backend.MyServlet.doPost(MyServlet.java:81)
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I know links are no appreciated here, but I pretty much copied this code and it worked.. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/firebase-appengine-backend

Comment: It worked, thank you. If you put it as an answer i'll accept it.